# Outlook 2013 autodiscover failing on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, autodiscovery, outlook-2013

I have recently got a new computer with windows 10 and I having a problem with autodiscover with Windows 10, outlook 2013, and Exchange 2010. Basically, my scheduling assistant, out of office, and autodiscover are not working. Scheduling Assistant shows everyone greyed out, Out of office is unable to contact the server, autodiscover fails all attempts when testing. I do have other users that have windows 10 that are running outlook 2013 with no issues.

I have tried all these features in OWA and everything works without issue.

I am getting the following error in the event logs of the exchange server.

Inbound authentication failed with error LogonDenied for Receive connector Default EXCH1. The authentication mechanism is Ntlm. The source IP address of the client who tried to authenticate to Microsoft Exchange is (192.168.*.*) which is my IP address.

Autodiscover fails with (0x80072ef3) error

I have tried rebuilding my profile and that has made no difference. I have also tried reinstalling Outlook. I do have a windows 7 machine running outlook 2013 and everything is working.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is this a domain joined computer? Are you logging in to the computer with the same account for the mailbox you are trying to access? Have you cleared out any saved passwords? How about creating a new Outlook profile and re-adding the Exchange accoutn?

Comment: Yes, it is a domain computer. I am logging in as a domain user. My account is a domain admin account so I should have access to all mailboxes. I have cleared out all the cache that I could find and temp files. I have also created a new profile which fixed my mailtips issue not working.

Comment: Specifically, are you logged on to the computer with the SAME account as the mailbox you are having trouble with. And in Exchange, being a domain admin does not give you access to other mailboxes.

Comment: Yes, I am logged into the computer with the same account as the email. I believe I have  found my problem though. It turns MS Update KB3161949 was causing my issues. I have removed it and so far no problems. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing MS UPDATE KB3161949 solved my issues

Answer (score 0):

I had a bear of a time getting Office 2013 SP1 to work with exchange. I am running internally on our domain. The final resolution was DNS. We did not have an internal DNS entry for autodiscover.domain.com set to point to the internal IP of the exchange server.  Once I did that all worked fine.

What I did for a test was added a registry entry where outlook has a list of the autodiscover server entries.  I added one using our IP address. Outlook worked with SP1.

Hope this helps
Dave